# Tinymodels' step_unknown is not carried over in after tuning

Tags: r, tidymodels

I use step_unknown as a quick imputation method for missing values by assigning them as a new level - 'unknown'. I expect that after training the workflow, the recipe should be fully estimated and ready to be applied for the test set. Factor variables with missing values in the test set should be recoded with the new 'unknown' level. However, this is not true as can be seen in the following toy example:

- var x2 contains missing value and it is not recoded as 'unknown'. hence, the random forest model (ranger) coerces these into NA.

**Set up toy dataset**

```
set.seed(135)
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(100),
  x2 = base::sample(c('a','b','c','d'), 100, replace = T),
  y = base::sample(c('p','n'), size = 100, replace = T)
)

na_idx <- replicate(2,sample(c(0,1),100, replace =T, prob = c(0.9,0.2)))

df$x1[na_idx[,1]==1] = NA
df$x2[na_idx[,2]==1] = NA

colSums(is.na(df))

df_split <-  initial_split(df, strata = y)
df_train <- training(df_split)
df_test <- testing(df_split)
  
# Set fold
df_fold <- vfold_cv(df_train, v = 5)
```

**Set up recipe with step_unknown**

```
base_rec <- recipe(y ~ x1 + x2,
                 data = df) %>%
  step_meanimpute(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_unknown(-all_outcomes(), -all_numeric())
```

A quick look of the recipe after prep(). It detects missing values in var x2 and recoded them as "unknow"

```
> base_rec %>% prep()
Data Recipe

Inputs:

      role #variables
   outcome          1
 predictor          2

Training data contained 100 data points and 29 incomplete rows. 

Operations:

Mean Imputation for x1 [trained]
Unknown factor level assignment for x2 [trained]
```

**Set up random forest model and workflow **

```
# Set engine
rf_eng <- rand_forest(
  mtry = tune(),
  trees = 500,
  min_n = tune(),
  mode = 'classification'
  ) %>% 
  set_engine('ranger', importance = 'impurity')

# Set wf
wflow_rf <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(rf_eng) %>% 
  add_recipe(base_rec)
```

**Tuning**

```
tune_res <- tune_grid(
  wflow_rf,
  resamples = df_fold,
  grid = 2,
  metrics = metric_set(accuracy,roc_auc,f_meas),
  control = control_grid(verbose = T)
)
```

Result indicates that in fold 2, missing values in var x2 were not recoded as "unknow" and they were considered as novel levels

```
> tune_res$.notes
[[1]]
# A tibble: 0 x 1
# … with 1 variable: .notes <chr>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  .notes                                                                                                                             
  <chr>                                                                                                                              
1 model 1/2 (predictions): Novel levels found in column 'x2': NA. The levels have been removed, and values have been coerced to 'NA'.
2 model 2/2 (predictions): Novel levels found in column 'x2': NA. The levels have been removed, and values have been coerced to 'NA'.
```

A quick check of fold 2 training data and test data. we see that NA exist in training data. Hence, the recipe should pick up this and recode x2 for the test data of fold2. However, it seems to ignore it

*Training data*

```
> df_fold$splits$`2`$data %>% 
+     slice(df_fold$splits$`2`$in_id) %>% 
+     select(x2) %>% 
+     table(useNA = 'ifany')
.
   a    b    c    d <NA> 
  14   18   11   11    7
```

*Test data*

```
> df_fold$splits$`2`$data %>% 
+     slice(-df_fold$splits$`2`$in_id) %>% 
+     select(x2) %>% 
+     table(useNA = 'ifany')
.
   a    b    c    d <NA> 
   3    5    2    0    5
```

Comment: You appear to be using an old version of {recipes}. Can you install a newer version from CRAN and see if you still get this error? `step_meanimpute()` have been deprecated in favor of `step_impute_mean()`

Comment: Thanks @EmilHvitfeldt. I updated the recipes package to ver_1.0.3 and it worked as expected